# BERT to XLNET train model

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tf.keras, transformer-model

I'm trying to do something like this in XLNet but I can't find this part in the documentation, any help would be valuable, thanks!

```py
# we access the transformer model within our bert object using the bert attribute 
# (eg bert.bert instead of bert)

embeddings = bert.bert(input_ids, attention_mask=mask)[1]  # access pooled activations with [1]
```

(Instead of bert.bert I'm trying to do it with xlnet)

Comment: Can you clarify which library you are using? I'm assuming it is `huggingface-transformers`, but it might well be another one :)

Comment: Hi! Yes, it is huggingface-transformers and Tensorflow to add Dense layer, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, let's first see what exactly hides behind the `bert.bert` property. For this, we can inspect the source code of the library for the [`TFBertModel`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_tf_bert.py#L849) class. There, we can see that it is defined as

```py
self.bert = TFBertMainLayer(config, name="bert")
```

where the `TFBertMainLayer` is exactly what the name suggests - the main BERT transformer component. To be precise, it is defined as follows:

```py
# ...
self.embeddings = TFBertEmbeddings(config, name="embeddings")
self.encoder = TFBertEncoder(config, name="encoder")
self.pooler = TFBertPooler(config, name="pooler") if add_pooling_layer else None
# ...
```

If we check the [source code for `TFXLNetModel`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/xlnet/modeling_tf_xlnet.py#L1150), we can see that there is only one property as well, which is defined as

```py
self.transformer = TFXLNetMainLayer(config, name="transformer")
```

Since this is similar enough in its name, you should get the same result by simply calling `xlnet.transformer(...)`, although I can't guarantee that all the input parameters work the same.